# ESLint complaints with "Unexpected token" on class async method

Tags: javascript, eslint, ecmascript-2017

Given this class :

```
class Foo {
  async bar() {
    
  }
}
```

ESLint says that `bar` is an unexpected token. My `.eslintrc` file is this :

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "commonjs": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "sourceType": "module"
    },

    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "import"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "import/extensions": [
            ".js"
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: `async` functions are ES2017, ES6 doesn't support them

Comment: @FZs there, modified th tags. The question hasn't changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add the `ecmaversion` to the configuration file. It works with these settings :

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "commonjs": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaVersion": "2018"
    },

    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "import"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "import/extensions": [
            ".js"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: For reference, here's [a random source saying `async` isn't available until ecma 2016](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/) (so [one more than es6](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/language-options#specifying-environments)), which explains the original parser issue with async/await and why this (`"ecmaVersion": "2018"`) fixes it.